# Ruby on Rails Access column from belongs_to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing a CRUD and I have three tables clients, audit_cases and ra_cases.

The followings are the relationship of my models

```
    class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :audit_cases
    end


    class AuditCase < ActiveRecord::Base
            belongs_to :client
            has_many :ra_cases                
    end

    class RaCase < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :audit_case 
    end
```

Model

```
def index
    @a_cases = AuditCase.all
    @b_cases = RaCase.all
end
```

I'm trying to join these three tables and show in a view
The following script works successfully

```
    <tbody>
     <% @b_cases.each do |b_case| %>
      <tr>
       <td><%= b_case.audit_case.client.Client_name %></td>
       </tr>
     <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

But the following script have an error of undefined method `Client_name' for nil:NilClass

```
    <tbody>
     <% @a_cases.each do |a_case| %>
      <tr>
       <td><%= a_case.client.Client_name %></td>
       </tr>
     <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

I can get the client array 'Client:0x007ff7d662adb0' if I use

```
    <%= a_case.client %>
```

I'd like to know how could I modify my script if I want to extract parent's data from child(audit_cases) instead of from grandchild(ra_cases).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Due to some of the column "client.Client_name" are nil,
It works after I add this code "unless a_case.client.nil?"

```
<%= a_case.client.Client_name unless a_case.client.nil? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like each relation is required, so there may be some `AuditCase` records in your database that don't have `Client` records associated with them (or the Client record was destroyed). The consequence of that is that your view will raise an error because it tries to call a method on `nil`.

To get the view working, I would nil-guard it in some way. If you want to enforce a requirement around the client-case relationship, that's a different issue.

Here are some possible nil guard ideas:

```
# If you're using Ruby 2.3+, you can use the Safe Navigation Operator
<tbody>
 <% @a_cases.each do |a_case| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= a_case.client&.Client_name %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
</tbody>

# Rails also provides a #try method
<tbody>
 <% @a_cases.each do |a_case| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= a_case.client.try(:Client_name) %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
</tbody>

# or just a rough nil check
<tbody>
 <% @a_cases.each do |a_case| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= a_case.client.Client_name if a_case.client %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Let me know if that works.

From a ruby style perspective, I would avoid capitalizing methods like `Client_name`. Capitalization defines a constant/class in ruby.